# Why does sourcing a script within R's parallel functions fail?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am using R's base parallel library where within a `parLapply` a script is sourced. In one case if I place the code inline, results are as expected. In another case if I replace the code with a call to `source()` pointing to a script with the exact same code, the code fails.

A reproducible example:

```
require(parallel)

# generate a list of random vectors with increasing means
set.seed(1)
x <- lapply(1:4, function(i) rnorm(10,i,1))

# create cluster and export the above list
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(4)
clusterExport(cl, varlist=c("x"))

# use inline code first
means.inline <- parLapply(cl, 1:length(x), function(i) {
  values <- x[[i]]
  mean(values)
})

# now call the exact same code, but sourced from a separate script
means.source <- parLapply(cl, 1:length(x), function(i) {
  source("code.R")
})
stopCluster(cl)
```

The contents of `code.R` are simply the same code in the first parLapply:

```
values <- x[[i]]
mean(values)
```

The first `parLapply` executes and calculates means as expected. The second `parLapply` fails:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  4 nodes produced errors; first error: object 'i' not found
```

Answer (score 2):

From `?source`:

> source causes R to accept its input from the named file or URL or
>   connection. Input is read and parsed from that file until the end of
>   the file is reached, then the parsed expressions are evaluated
>   sequentially in the **chosen environment**.

The clue is in the mention of "chosen environment" and then a peek at the `local` argument for `source`:

> TRUE, FALSE or an environment, determining where the parsed
>   expressions are evaluated. FALSE (the default) corresponds to the
>   user's workspace (the global environment) and **TRUE to the environment
>   from which source is called.**

This means that `source(code.R)` results in the script being read and parsed in the global environment by default, not the individual function environments within `parLapply`.

To get the required behavior:

`source("code.R", local=TRUE)`

Comment: I think you're confusing two types of environments: function environments and "thread" environments.

Comment: @hadley So you mean the difference between the global and parLapply environment versus the global and the "thread" environment?

Comment: The documentation is referring to R environments, whereas a "thread" environment is not well defined since it depends on the underlying parallelisation engine (and is unlikely to be threads)

Comment: Using your answer the result has not the same structure as the inline code version: Now it returns a list of list with two elements in the inner list: value + visible: `> means.inline
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2`... vs. `> means.source
[[1]]
[[1]]$value
[1] 1.132203

[[1]]$visible
[1] TRUE


[[2]]
[[2]]$value
[1] 2.248845

[[2]]$visible
[1] TRUE`... Do I miss something? Linux with R3.3.0

Comment: Would any one consider this an acceptable answer? Looks like Andy and Hadley had some differences; Currently running into a memory leak issue in a sourced script with uses `parLapply` and getting a memory leak.